# Sass/Compass/Foundation compilation error

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass, yeoman

am currently using yo and migrating an existing project to it .. I've installed foundation via bower and referenced it from my existing _settings.scss file in the app/styles folder correctly ... my css compiled in a very weird way like so

```
@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-family:file\:\/\/\/Users\/instabug\/Documents\/instabug\/angular-demo\/instabug2\/bower_components\/foundation\/scss\/foundation\/components\/_visibility\.scss}
```

There are about hundred errors that read the same thing, that the font-family property is given a weird \8293281 number instead of a font name.

What's wrong here?

*Edit1:*

Angular generator doesn't use the config.rb file instead it's using the Gruntfile.js to pass in the compass config, and her is the snippet that has to do with compass

```
compass: {
  options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
    generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
    imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
    javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
    fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
    importPath: './bower_components',
    httpImagesPath: '/images',
    httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
    httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
    relativeAssets: false,
    assetCacheBuster: false,
    raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
    }
  },
  server: {
    options: {
      debugInfo: false
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Coud you post your config.rb file ?

Comment: I've used the angular generator by the yo team, and it should have been providing everything out of the box ... it's not using a config.rb file instead the config is in the Gruntfile.js I'll update the question